# jQuery simple array

Tags: jquery, arrays, contains

Hi I'm trying to build a simple array where it searches through an array of names in list items and changes the text in jQuery

My current code is:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            var xNames = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"];
            console.log(xNames);

            xNames = $.grep(xNames, function() {

                $('li:contains(xNames)').children("#products")
                                        .children(".pay-mo")
                                        .html("<p>&nbsp;</p><p class='cost'>&nbsp;</p><p class='stock'><strong>No longer available</strong></p>")
                                        .css("display", "block");
                $(".pay-mo").css("display", "block");
            });
        });
```

Any simple ideas to get this to work?

Comment: You are not using `$.grep` correctly (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/). Since you didn't really explain what you want to achieve, it's difficult to make a suggestion.

Comment: If you say what's not working maybe we can help out.

Comment: OK Its difficult to explain but, I have a list of items which have text in list items <li> I can't edit the text because its dynamically generated so I'm using jQuery to change it. Not ideal, but i'm limited on access.

Comment: grep is new to me and this is from my final attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `:contains`.  `$.grep` is for searching the array.

```
$.each(xNames, function () {
    $("li:contains(" + this + ")").children("#products") // etc.
});
```

Note that `:contains` is just if the name is *contained*.  You may want to compare to `.text` instead.

Comment: Hi Explosion thanks for your solution, this works although it picks up everything which contains the text i search for e.g 'name1' would also pick up 'name1 more' anyway to exact match only?

Comment: @MatthewWhite you would have to compare to `.text()`.